# C++ Custom List template

Tags: c++

I am trying to create a custom List template in C++ but haven't gotten very far! I have the skeleton of the coding done and am now trying to fill it in. Basically, I would like it to be possible to create a new list where the two nodes (first, last) will be NULL until values are added into the list.

However, there is a huge error message which seems to be a i/o one. It is too long to paste here. I'm sure I am doing something silly that will be spotted by those more experienced then me.

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

template <class T>
class node {
    T value;
    node<T> *next;
    node<T> *previous;  
};

template <class T>
class my_list {
    public:
         node<T> first;
         node<T> last;
         my_list(){
            first = NULL;
            last = NULL;
         }
        ~my_list(){
         }
         void push_back(T val);
 };

template <class T>
void my_list<T>::push_back(T val){
if (this->first == NULL) {
    cout << "Hello";
}
}

int main() {
my_list<int> newlist;
newlist.push_back(5);
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to fix your declaration of `first` and `last`:

```
node<T> *first;
node<T> *last;
```

Comment: Thank you! Not a chance I would have been able to work that out. Would have been staring blankly at the screen for hours.